# Tooltip fade in and out nice and slow

Tags: jquery, css, image, tooltip

I have a little Tooltip creation that I have done for a website, But I would like to make the fadeIn and fadeOut very smooth..

I have this, and would like any help on how I should do and a little bit of explanation of the way I should structure this in future so I am aware, (new to jQuery!)

```
<script>
  $(function() {
      $("#logo img[title]").tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

So how would I make this fade in and fade out, I tried loads of alternative's but I know I am putting thing's in the wrong place, probably an easy thing for some of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the [Tooltip](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip) plugin for jQuery, you'll probably want this to set up fading:

```
$("#logo img[title]").tooltip({ fade: 250 });
```